# Discover multipart features in a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, multipart, qgis-1

I am trying to identify multipart features using QGIS version is 1.8.0.

I've tried:

1. look at the attributes table
2. select a random feature and check in the canvas if there are
   multiple geometries selected
3. repeat until found one or all features have been examined

What I would like to check is something like a Boolean value in the Layer properties!

Comment: Which Version and what have you tried to find multi-part features?

Comment: The version is 1.8.0 and what I tried is : 1) look at the attributes table, 2) select a random feature and check in the canvas if there are multiple geometries selected, 3) repeat until found one or all features have been examined.

Comment: please put this info in your question to be re-opened.

Comment: Ok, done.. sorry!

Comment: If I recall this can be done with a simple field calculation in ArcGIS, but I don't know about QGIS. If you *only* want to identify them, you could make use of the Topology Checker plugin and use the 'must not have multi-part geometries' rule but I believe that will require a newer version of QGIS. If you're ok with breaking them up rather than just identifying, there's the multi-part to single-part tool, though again that may require a newer version.

Comment: The Topology Checker is what I would have wanted, thank you! Too bad I have to change the sw version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm on QGIS 2.4; not sure if this will work in 1.8!

Start an edit session on the layer and add a new field called multi - an integer, single-digit.

For the expression, enter:

```
CASE WHEN  geomToWKT( $geometry ) LIKE '%MULTI%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This will give you a 1 for each row when it's a multi-part line or polygon.

Comment: It seems that geomToWKT( $geometry ) gives NULL, I was looking up for a sort of reference to discover when this happens but I found nothing. can you please explain me this ?

Comment: I suspect that's happening because of the older version (1.8). Why not upgrade to 2.4? Basic functionality the same but far, far more features and much better performance.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was thinking of for ArcGIS, except the expression uses `!shape.isMultipart!` - I didn't know how to do that in QGIS, and it appears the version might play a role as well.

Comment: I was trying avoid the version switching to keep the one which my Professor used during the lectures, but I ended up doing it anyway. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a pretty significant upgrade in terms of capability and performance - and I doubt that much will be different to the one used in your lectures. Thanks!

Comment: 2022 and with QGIS 3.22 this still works perfectly fine. IDK if there's a better way by now. But I found this solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I tried to use the code from here: https://gist.github.com/timlinux/9179a2fc619a26c3ad4a, but when I ran it, all the features were selected.

Then I modified the code (here: https://gist.github.com/dimasmaulana99/93f28c1056337822a11c823633e272a6), and now I can only select multipart features.

[image: Example of using it]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).