# Using Union tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-processing, union

Here is my scenario:

**I am trying to use Union to combine the land and mangrove shapefiles in QGIS and to compute for the areas of each individual geometry.**

What I did:

*First, I cleaned them. Upon checking the attributes, it appeared that there are duplicate features in the mangrove.shp,so I used 'Delete duplicate geometries' in the Processing Toolbox. I used Union to combine the land and mangrove shps,and again, some of the geometries were duplicated, so I repeated the process of deleting the duplicates.*

Is it already ensured that the individual features have their individual attributes, or do I still have to use Multiple Parts to Single Parts?

Comment: Please use a title describing the actual question you have. And do use ONE question per post. This site is designed as a question->answer system, not a forum.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Multipart is not the same as duplicate geometries. A multipart polygon is one feature/row in the table but with multiple parts, for example some group of islands. From what you describe you have not done anything that will change multiparts to single parts. You can check if you have multipart features like this: [Discover multipart features in a layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119655/discover-multipart-features-in-a-layer-in-qgis)